# Is it possible to write ActionScript programs in Notepad or Notepad++?

Tags: actionscript, notepad++, notepad

Is it possible to write ActionScript programs in Notepad or Notepad++? I mean, I don't want to buy the whole Adobe Flash program, but I have a Flash plugin installed in a browser, and since  Flash suite is merely an IDE for ActionScript, it should be possible to write in the language itself without the Adobe program?

Answer (score 2):

Use [flashdevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/), it's an open source ActionScript editor.
But it does not provide the graphic tools included in Flash.

Answer (score 1):

If notepad++ can save as an actionscript file, that feature should be there for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the [Eclipse IDE](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) with the [ActionScript3 plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/as3ide/)?